# how to find network status

Tags: c#, forms

I want to write a program in C# that recognize now computer connected to internet or not by C#.
Would you help me how to do that, I have no idea about it,because I didnt work network in C#.

one more question,how I can run a program from c# and sent argument also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10057885/check-if-machine-is-connected-to-internet.aspx) is a simple example on how you can check if your computer is connected to the internet.

[Here](http://dotnetperls.com/process-start) is another example on how to launch a program in C#. You can check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) msdn page for more information on the `Process` class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx) method to test DNS:

```
public static bool IsConnected()
{
    try
    {
        var entry = Dns.GetHostEntry("www.google.com");
        return true;
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As far as the second part of your question is concerned about command line arguments you would pass them at the command prompt:

```
c:\>foo.exe param1 param2
```

and you could fetch them as a string array in your Main method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // args will represent a string array of command line 
        // arguments passed to your application. It will be an
        // empty array if no arguments were passed
    }
}
```