# find network status

Tags: c#

I want to write a program in C# that recognize now computer connected to internet or not by C#.
Would you help me how to do that, I have no idea about it,because I didnt work network in C#.

one more question,how I can run a program from c# and sent argument also?

Comment: Answer to question #2: [Debugging with command-line parameters in Visual Studio.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/298708/94928)

Comment: Better for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Since being migrated, this is now a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361557/how-to-find-network-status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Microsoft's [**InternetGetConnectedState**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384702%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

You can call it with P/Invoke:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConnectionState
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int lpdwFlags, int dwReserved);

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int flags;
            bool isConnected = InternetGetConnectedState(out flags, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Is connected: {0} Flags:{1}", isConnected, flags));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```